# Bootstrap Modal not showing properly when rendered by chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am writing a chrome extension where I working on a webpage which lists some things. So, basically, I am reading that table and doing some calculation in the javascript and showing them in a modal. The image below somewhat shows that:
[image]

The data in the image is removed intentionally. I am facing a problem in the modal that it is not coming properly, i.e I am getting mymodal bigger than modal-content. I can fix it by adding a margin-bottom to some value. It does work but if I change the screen resolution, then it does not get adjusted. 
Please find below the code for this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementById("modalClose");

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    };

    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-collapse")[0];
    element.classList.remove("collapse");

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    };

    var button = document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0];

    button.onclick = function(event) {
        if(button.value === 'Switch to Values') {

        }
    }
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head> 
<body>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal" style="top: 50%; bottom: 0%; left: 40%; right: 50%; width: 60%; margin-bottom: 110px; ">
      <div class="modal-content" style="border-radius: 0px;">
          <div class="modal-header" style="text-align: center;">
            <span id="modalClose" class="close">&times;</span>
            <h3>XYZ</h3>
            <button type="button" class="btn" style="float: right;">Switch to Values</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align: center;">
              <p id= "footer-text">
                dsajdsal
              </p>
          </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I am putting the data using javascript code which is coming fine. Another problem I am facing in this, if I don't add top: 50%; bottom: 0%; left: 40%; right: 50%; width: 60%; in myModal element, then the modal comes in top left corner. I am not sure why by default, it is coming in the top left corner. Thats why added some css to bring it in center. Apart from that, I didn't do any other customization.

These are the 2 major problems I am facing. Can someone help me in these? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you add a fiddle please?

Comment: @Viira The problem is this problem is not occurring when I am creating the modal normally. It's only happening, when I am creating the modal from google chrome extension.

Comment: The modal elements are being affected by the CSS of the current page. For example the div of that webpage must be styled in a way that they are off by some pixels. That's why you need to ''negate' those effects by adding your css as you mentioned.